# Plugin architecture, menu and services - Extensible context based menus

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony, knpmenubundle

Currently I am writing an app that shall be extended using bundles.

Now the app registered the menu "related" as a service.
Bundle A shall be able to extend the menu and add a link to "imprint".
Bundle B shall be able to extend the menu by adding "disable" and "rename" menu items,
but only when the current doctrine entity is `\App\Entity\User`.

The target routes will need the ID of the current shown doctrine entity.

Currently I am doing this via events. But as those things above are not events the attempt is wrong.
In addition I don't know how to access or register the current shown doctrine repo / entity.

How to correctly solve this in Symfony?

Is there a neat way to save some performance?
I am thinking of code that will be executed with every request.
Someone in the IRC/Freenode told me, that Symfony has some solutions to avoid such calls for "almost static data".

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your need, but since you talk about menus you may want to take a look at the Symfony CMF project http://cmf.symfony.com/, and precisely to its `RoutingBundle` which adds dynamic routing features.

Comment: Woah. This is nice! Brought me the PHPCR which will be implemented ;) Actually I build a CRM for me but I might steal some of the bundles named in your link ;D -- Thank you very much!